# From google maps api to rich snippet geocoords

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I'm stuck in implementing rich snippets on my website.
The page respects the schema.org/MusicEvent standard. But I cannot figure out how to extract the coordinates pair contained in ncenter to fill the longitude and latitude meta-tags in the html code.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
var ncenter;
function initialize() {

    var address = document.getElementById("address").firstChild.data;
    geocoder.geocode( {'address':address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            ncenter = results[0].geometry.location;
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom:12,
                center:ncenter,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map:map,
                position:ncenter
            });             

        } else { 
           alert("Geocode ERROR: " + status);
        }
        });
}
window.onload=initialize;
```

Moreover this won't work with search engines spiders, because they don't run JS. 
Is there any alternative solution (a php based query maybe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write the contents of the metatag using javascript, e.g. (with jQuery):

```
$('body').append('<div itemprop="geo">' + 
'<meta itemprop="latitude" content="' + ncenter.lat() + '" />' + 
'<meta itemprop="longitude" content="' + ncenter.lng() + '" />' + 
'</div>');
```

Or yes, you could write this out using PHP instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I finally chose to implement a solution based on PHP, thanks to the XML geocoder. 
I parsed the XML to find latitude and longitude and filled the meta tags with a simple echo. Then the JS has just to get the content value of the meta-tags to build the coordinates pair and create a map with center and marker in that point.